# RegExp to match words wrapped in braces

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, templates, match

In javascript, I've got a block of HTML like this:

```
<h2>{title}</h2>
<p><a href="{url}">{content}</a></p>
```

And I'm trying use regex "match" to spit out an array of all the {item}'s. So my output should look like:

```
['title', 'url', 'content']
```

I've gotten as far as:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("\{[a-zA-Z]+\}+");
var match = pattern.exec("{Sample} bob {text}");
```

But it's only returning the first tag.

This is just beyond my regex skills. Can anyone help?

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a pattern with the global flag:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("\{[a-zA-Z]+\}", "g");
```

or:

```
var pattern = /\{[a-zA-Z]+\}/g;
```

Then you can call the match() method on your string to get a list of matches:

```
var matches = "{Sample} bob {text}".match(pattern);
```

Comment: I think "\{[^}]+\}" is a safer bet than "\{[a-zA-Z]\}", but if there are no other letters/symbols in Corey's model I guess it's okay. +1

Comment: Not at all.  Corey himself used [a-zA-Z] so I kept that.  A regex should always be as strict as possible, never as loose as possible.  If one day Corey has an HTML file with a missing }, [^}]+ will run haywire, while [a-zA-Z] won't.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("\{[a-zA-Z]+\}+", "g");
```

The second option is a flag telling it to search the entire string and return all matches.

See: http://www.evolt.org/article/Regular_Expressions_in_JavaScript/17/36435/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Much as I like to roll my own RegExp (and you really just need the global flag), have you looked at [prototype templates](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/template), [Trimpath JST](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplates) or anything like that?

Because possibly rolling your own won't be as efficient for reuse as the above examples. EG:

```
String.prototype.template = function (obj) {
 return this.replace(/{([^{}]+)}/g,
  function (full, word) {
   return((typeof obj[word]==='string'||typeof obj[word]==='number')?obj[word]:full);
  }
 );
};

"The {adj1} {adj2} {noun}.".template({adj1: 'lazy',adj2: 'brown', noun: 'dog'})
==> "The lazy brown dog."
```

This runs your regex each time, while I believe the prototype templates basically does it once.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this yet?

```
<script>
var text = '<h2>{title}</h2>\n<p><a href="{url}">{content}</a></p>';
var regex = /\{[a-z]+\}/ig;
var result = text.match(regex);
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    console.debug(i + ". " + result[i]);
}
/*
gives:
0. {title}
1. {test}
2. {url}
3. {content}
*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got off path by using `exec` for testing.